# How to get permanent link to a file with BitBucket server?

Tags: bitbucket-server

Sometimes I want to provide a link to some source code in the comment to an issue.
If I open repository in browser and find the fileI need, the link refers to `master` branch by default. It means that over time the code referred by the link will change, because the `master` will move together with commits history.

In GitHub and GitLab when you want to get a permanent link on a file you just opened, it is enough to press `y` on the keyboard and the link will switch from referring the master branch to particular commit hash it points to.

I.e. `https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/blob/master/README` -> `https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/blob/7fd1a60b01f91b314f59955a4e4d4e80d8edf11d/README`

At work I use BitBucket server (v7.10.1, if it matters) and unfortunately the `y` does not work, and I also do not see any button on UI to get permanent link. How can I achieve the same result (get permanent link) on BitBucket server?

I know a couple of tricks I am not satisfied with:

- using [Bitbucket Linky](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8015-bitbucket-linky) plugin for Intellij, but I want a more light-weight way
- pressing **History** button on a file, and choosing the most recent one (but it does not give you the `master` hash, it gives the hash of the last change of the file. And also this button won't work if the file has a single version and never changed after the 1st commit)

Answer (score 3):

Got to the version you want, and then click 'Raw file' (top right hand side of screen)

[image]

The path in the address bar should now be a permanent link. It will be the raw version of the file unfortunately, but it is a permanent link.